# Defining a logarithm function that translates into a value that I can easily graph

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

I'm trying to create a logarithmic bar chart on Visio. Using Visio's coordinate system, I defined the following values for $f(x)$:

- $$f(0) = 200,000$$
- $$f(10) = 341,248$$
- $$f(100) = 482,496$$
- $$f(1000) = 623,744$$
- $$f(10000) = 764,992$$
- $$f(100,000) = 906,240$$

I've spent the weekend trying to figure out how I can define a function that maintains the defined values relationship. I'm stuck.

What are the steps to determining a function that will give me these values? I want to be able to plug-in, say, f(30) and the resulting value is a coordinate value on my Visio project that I can just type-in easily to position the individual bar charts.

Since this is not a Visio specific question, I figured I'd ask here because I want to understand the process of how you all go about solving this type of problem.

Thank you!

Comment: try $$y=a\log(bx+c)+e$$

Comment: Change you first entry into $f(\color{red}{1})=200000$ then plot $\log (x) $ against $f(x)$. Should be pretty linear.

Comment: Assuming you can set $f(1) = 200000$ instead of $f(0)$, then an easy formula would be $f(x) = 200000 +141248 \log_{10}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you all! What steps did you take to come up with such a formula? Did you do it via trial and error? Or is there a method that I can repeatedly apply in the future?

Comment: It’s just that $f(0)$ doesn’t belong in your list: all the other numbers are related by a ratio of $10$ between successive values of the variable. Your “$0$” doesn’t fit.

Answer (score 1):

Your data fit perfectly to $f(n)=200,000+141,248\log_{10}n$ as long as the argument of the first data point is $n=1$ instead of $n=0$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you get to such a function?

Comment: I just looked at the data.  The increment between the lines is constant.  As the argument is multiplied by $10$ each line (except from the first to the second) the $\log_{10}$ was easy to see.